# unexpected output from arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have following arrow function.

```
var a = 10;
var b = 5;
var str = (a,b) => ("sum: "+(a+b));

str();
```

I expected the output to be

`sum: 15`

but the output is

`sum: NaN`

why?

Comment: var a = 10;
var b = 5;

var str = (a,b) 

str = a+b;
15

Comment: you need to pass the arguments `str(a, b); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the arguments `a` and `b` in call to function

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 5;
var str = (a, b) => ("sum: " + (a + b));
console.log(str(a, b));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 10;

var b = 5;

var str = (a, b) => ("sum: " + (a + b));

str(a, b); // You have to call the function with parameters.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass parameters `str(a,b)`.

```
var a = 10;
var b = 5;
var str = (a,b) => ("sum: "+(a+b));

str(a,b);
```